# How do I parse the toc.ncx file within an ePub document and display its hierarchy?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, epub

I have my application to read and display an ePub file almost ready.

What I am looking now into is, if my table of contents for the book has a hierarchical structure for chapters, topics and subtopics, how do I parse the toc.ncx file (which has an XML structure), and load the data in a UITableView while preserving the hierarchical structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSXMLParser to parse the toc.ncx file. It's pretty straight forward, you can find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003773).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am actually able to parse the file succesfully, but i am facing trouble while getting the hierarchical details of the file and presenting the same hierarchy in the UITableView format.

Comment: Clearly, your question cannot be answered without more detailed information.

Comment: Yup !!! Finally i got it... First i need to parse the XML and create a dictionary out of it... And then this NSDictionary can be easily displayed in UITableView in Hierarchical format !!